# Pay Dialog not showing and returns callback error - UserCanceled (1383010)

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I use Unity Facebook SDK, a wrapper of js SDK.
When I call FB.Canvas.Pay API the js SDK doesn't show Pay Dialog; instead, it returns a callback with the error.
Furthermore, this issue doesn't happen in one ENV, however, the client codebase is the same.
I assume there might be some settings for imitating such a flow, but I can't find it in the Facebook app dashboard or in the documentation.
This error is usually returned when a user closes the popup, but in my case, it does not appear at all.

I checked the app settings in Facebook app dashboard, read the related documentation, but there is no information about this flow